# Create two dependent vector on Octave

Tags: arrays, vector, vectorization, octave

I want to vectorize this Octave code:

```
v = [10];
a = f(v^2)
dx = 0.1;
for i = 1:100
  dv = a/v(i)*dx;
  v = [v, v(i)+dv];
endfor
```

`a` depends on `v`, and `v` depends on `a`.
How can I do that?

Comment: Can you post your code with the for loop? The ability to vectorize will largely depend on the specific operations to be carried out on the vector elements.

Comment: "depends on" is undefined

Comment: Please provide a sample of inputs along with exact expected output. Please provide your solution with loop that you want to vectorize. Please [edit] your question to include a  [mcve] of your problem. Please note that there is no such thing as octave (matlab). If you're looking for a solution that is compatible for both languages then mention it explicitly. Otherwise please remove the irrelated tag.

Comment: Main message edited, thanks

Comment: Instead of `v = [v, v(i)+dv]`, it's better to write `v(end+1) = v(i)+dv`. And by replacing `a` with its definition and then `dv` with its definition, we end up with `v2(end+1) = v2(i)+P*dx/m/(v2(i)^2)`. I don't see a way to vectorize such an expression. You can move the `P*dv/m` part outside of the loop, there's no need to recompute that every loop iteration, as those values are constants.

Comment: You're right, but this is a simpler code that I wrote to post here. In the real code, acceleration is quadratic function of speed "v", and is a step function dependent on speed. Thus, I can't remove it